# Hide and Show UIBarButtonItem with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, ios11, swift4

I want to hide and show my `UIBarButtonItem` but since Swift 4 and iOS 11, it doesn't work anymore. Why ?

**Code for hide :**

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
```

**Code for show :**

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.barButtonItem
```

**Before :**

[image: UIBarButtonItem is display]

**During :**

[image: When I tap on my SearchBar]

**After :**

[image: When I click on Cancel, UIBarButtonItem not appear]

Comment: Where you are hiding `rightBarButtonItem`?

Comment: When UISearchBar begin editing.

Comment: Have you found the solution bro?

Answer (score -2):

You can try this, if you use standard elements. You can also first create your UIBarButtonItem and allocate it within the following code again:

```
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action: "barButtonItemClicked:"), animated: true)
```

For reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624929-setrightbarbutton

Comment: you are not using the given functionality setRightBarButtonItem(...) of your navigationItem. I assume allocating the barButtonItem directly (your code) was working in swift3 but not in swift4